# Passing value in method(java) as an argument

Tags: java, methods, encoding, enums, syntax

I have created an Enum

```html
public enum Fruit {
mango , banana , apple , guava;

}
```

I have a function in which I want to pass enum as an argument and use that parameter.
The function is like this

```html
getFruits(Fruit.apple)  // calling function


public void getFruit( **What to write here to use that Fruit enum**) {
double sweetValue = sweetValueOfFruit( **how can i pass Fruit.apple here**)
}
```

Assume **sweetValue** function is defined somewhere.

**Please help me in writing code for it** (for all in between ** **).
Thanks, community :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fruit is enum so use create object of it same way as you do with class

```
public void getFruits( Fruit aFruit) {
    double sweetValue = sweetValueOfFruit( aFruit);
}
```

it recommended for naming convention to make all enum to be capital letter

so it be like that

```
public enum Fruit {
    MANGO , BANANA , APPLE , GUAVA;
}
```

Comment: Thanks buddy , Here aFruit can be anything either apple , banana , mango or guava , suppose that aFruit is MANGO , then how can we write it as in form of Fruit.MANGO (using aFruit) .

Comment: aFruit is variable name (you can name it whatever you like it only care that it to be of Fruit type) so no matter what value you called this method with aFruit will be equal to it  

so 
getFruits(Fruit.apple) or getFruits(Fruit.mango) or getFruits(Fruit.banana)

it will make afruit equal to Fruit.apple or  Fruit.mango and so on

Comment: Thankyou very much !! God bless you